# Changing Character Value of Active Cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string-decoding

I am trying to write a VBA macro that takes a single letter of the alphabet from the active cell and replaces it with a letter five positions ahead (i.e. "a" becomes "f", "x" becomes "c"). This is to decode a file of encrypted text where all letters have been shifted back five positions.

So far I have tried using the ASCII value of the letter and converting from that integer back to a character, but this seems not to be working (run time error 13) and I can't help but wonder if there is a more efficient way. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub DECODER()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim What As String
What = ActiveCell.Value

Dim dCode As String
If What = "" Then
dCode = What
Else
dCode = Chr(Asc((What) + 5))
End If

ActiveCell.Value = dCode

End Sub
```

Comment: You have your parenthesis in the wrong places `dCode = Chr(Asc(What) + 5)`

Answer (score 1):

**Without VBA:**

With a single lower case alphabetic character in cell **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=CHAR(IF(CODE(A1)>117,CODE(A1)-26,CODE(A1))+5)
```

[image]

and **With VBA:**

```
Public Function DeCoder(Sin As String) As String
    Dim num As Long

    If Sin Like "[a-z]" Then
        num = Asc(Sin) + 5
        If num > 122 Then num = num - 26
        DeCoder = Chr(num)
    Else
        DeCoder = Sin
    End If
End Function
```